# Show the script field in a custom Unity Inspector for StateMachineBehaviours

Tags: unity-game-engine, customization

Usually I would use the following method in a [CustomEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for displaying the Script field of a component in the inspector

```c#
private void DrawScriptField()
{
    // Disable editing
    EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true); 
    EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((MyClass) target), typeof(MyClass), false);
    EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
}
```

My problem is `MonoScript` apparently only contains the two methods `FromMonoBehaviour` and `FromScriptableObject` but there is no method for getting the script from a `StateMachineBehaviour`.

**How can I make a similar script field in a custom editor for a `StateMachineBehaviour` script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh never mind. I overead that [`StateMachineBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) actually inherits from `ScriptableObject` so I can simply use `MonoScript.FromScriptableObject`.